# How to remove line breaks after <td> in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, text-editor

Line breaks after `<td>` tags in aspx pages cause line breaks to be output in the html causing text to expand into multi lines.

Is there a way in Visual Studio, Resharper or online formatter which removes these type of line feeds? I don't want to remove every single line feed.. just the ones after`<td>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Regex in Find-and-Replace in Visual Studio.

here \r?\n match a line break

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could open your source files in SublimeText, do a find->replace.  Enable regular expressions (the .* button) and then use these values:

find: \n
replace:

Sorry I don't have a VisualStudio related solution